# Checkbox outline border color is not properly displayed i n IE browser

Tags: html, css

Please refer below code:

```
<div>
   <input type="checkbox"/>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
input
{
    outline: 2px solid gray;
}
```

fiddle link :

http://jsfiddle.net/SVDwQ/

In chrome browser screenshot looks like below

[image]

In IE looks like below :

[image]

I need same look as it displayed in chrome ? why the appearance different in IE browser.

i want to display the check box outline same in both browser.

Thanks,

Siva

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE (except for 11) is adding 3px of padding around the checkbox:

```
input {
    outline: 2px solid gray;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SVDwQ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding css reset code like [this one](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

```
    /* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```